# NetLink with SsfPack (a .dll) for use in State Space Time Series

Tags: time-series, .netlink

I have recently been doing work in the field of State Space Time Series.  Mathematica does not have a lot of built in tools for working in this area.  There is a well known package that is available, SsfPack, that should help bridge that gap.  I am having trouble getting that package to work within Mathematica.

You can read about the package [here](http://www.ssfpack.com) and download [here](http://www.ssfpack.com/files/ssfpack_basic_302.zip).  Inside the zip is a starting guide and use guide.

The site states, "SsfPack is a suite of C routines for carrying out computations involving the statistical analysis of time series models in state space form." It then states, "SsfPack is primarily developed as a module for the object-oriented matrix programming language Ox. The library is written in C, which greatly improves execution speed compared to a direct Ox implementation."

This would make me think that it is a program written in C that should work with Library link.

In the zip file there is a couple headers (.h files) as well as a couple .dll files.

I have tried

```
Needs["NETLink`"]
kalfil=DefineDLLFunction["KalmanFil", filepath, "long", {"long"}]
During evaluation of In[4]:= LinkOpen::linke: Could not find MathLink executable.
During evaluation of In[4]:= InstallNET::fail: A link to the .NET runtime could not be established.
During evaluation of In[4]:= DefineDLLFunction::netlink: DefineDLLFunction cannot operate because InstallNET[] failed to launch the .NET runtime.
$Failed
```

I think having this package available to Mathematica users would really help.  Maybe it only works with the Ox programming language?

Comment: LibraryLink requires special structures in your source code to work. You may use NetLink to load functions in a dll file directly.

Comment: @xslittlegrass thank you for the clarification.  I have tried Needs["NETLink`"] DefineDLLFunction["KalmanFil",filepath,Real,Real] to no avail.  I will post that code and amend the question later today.